# How do you keep mobs from despawing?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

In Minecraft PE I want to make a sheep farm, but I'm afraid they will despawn. There are no name tags in mcpe, so how do I do this without modding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passive mobs do not despawn.

Hostile mobs are the only ones that do.

Answer (score 0):

If you dye the sheep then the game registers that they are your sheep and they won't despawn.

Comment: You can feed them, too. No need to dye them.